# Wrapping a mesh around point cloud with cavities

Tags: modeling, mesh, point-clouds

I have a series of point clouds I want to convert to mesh (there are points *inside* the object, uniformly distributed, not only on the surface).

I want to generate a model of the surface of the point cloud.

When the model is convex (like a cube or a sphere) applying a *convex hull* around the object is good enough but when the model has holes (like a torus (a.k.a. doughnut)) or cavities (like the area around the eyes in a head model or the area around the steam in a glass of wine) those concave features are lost.

**Is there a way to wrap a mesh around a point cloud in a *"convex hull style"* without loosing the cavities?**

It doesn't need to be perfect, a reasonable approximation of the geometry of the object would be good enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could compare the technique you currently use to a [ShrinkWrap Modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Shrinkwrap)

Here is a 10 times subdivided cube shrinkwrapped to a point cloud created from a torus.

[image]

In this image an extra vertex was added in the center:

[image]

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I'm looking for. For some reason the wrapping object does not shrink around the point cloud. Should the PC be connected by vertices before applying the modifier?

Comment: @Xocoatzin did you chose the mode nearest vertext as shown in the modifier settings (1st screenshot)?

Comment: That was it, works perfectly :)

Answer (score 9):

There is a cool addon called **[Point Cloud Skinner](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?241950-A-Script-to-Skin-a-Point-Cloud-%28for-Blender-2-6x-or-Later%29)** that can build mesh from point cloud data. (By Hans.P.G)

- Download and install it;
- Find the Point Cloud Skinner panel in **Scene** tab;
- Tweak the parameters as instructed until you get a good-enough result;
- For complicated data, additional manual fix may be required, such as filling holes or clearing elements.

[image]

Comment: Any technique to achieve this with Geometry Nodes?