# Preserve materials when joining meshes

Tags: modeling, materials

In [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29274/69628) is explained how to create an object which looks like a nucleus.

However, I have a problem when merging multiples spheres into one object. Exactly what I do is the following

1) I created a parent object with many spheres.

2) Then I do Object -> Apply -> Make duplicates real. This will give me all spheres, which are as before colored in red and blue.

3) I select all these spheres and Object-> Join (Ctrl-J). This gives me a single object that I would like to further use as a base object for other geometry.

But after step three all spheres become of the same color.

The question is how to preserve colors of individual spheres when Joining them into a single object?

Thanks in advance.
(I was using blender 2.80)

Comment: I don’t understand why this has been downvoted - whoever downvoted, please add explanation so the issue can be addressed. I’ve upvoted but perhaps their issue was with the title - perhaps change the title to something more generic (“preserve materials when joining meshes” perhaps)

Comment: Thank you. According to your recommendation I changed the title.

Comment: I think this is a good question. I think I would create a script that assigned a random vertex color on all vertex points on each object before joining them. Then create a material that uses the vertex color as an input to the shader. Or try to bake it to a texture... but that would require unique UV coordinates for each object... not good answers I'm afraid :-P

Comment: Are there any particular reason why you need to join the objects?

Comment: @Jackdaw I want to join spheres because later on I would like to create a crystal cell, i.e., cube, in vertices of which I have these nuclei. I was thinking to make an individual nucleus a parent for this cube and later use the same steps how I created nucleus itself. The description is in the links from the post.

Comment: @batFINGER I edited the post and removed the second question.

Comment: Cheers. As mentioned recommend  adding as [another separate question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)  I'm not really strong on material nodes, but imagine redoing  step 3 multiple times can  sometimes get all red and other times all blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a more suitable way of generating instances would be with a Particle System?

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> Make a Group of a proton and a neutron
- Make an Emitter object, (maybe a rounded cube, to avoid crunching at the poles?)
- Assign a Particle System to the emitter
- No physics, start and end frames at 1
- If you want to vary the proportion of neutrons and protons, you can 'Use Count' in the settings

Settings to taste, but this produced the illustrated result.

[image]

- Now you can hit 'Convert' in the modifier stack of the emitter.. and..
- ..<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> 'Make Duplicates Real'
- Because the material is not dependent on Object ID,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
  <kbd>J</kbd> preserves materials

[image]

Comment: But I still think you could do everything you describe without joining duplis into a single mesh.. and the option would be left open to have your nuclei components jiggle about.. but that would be another question..

Answer (score 0):

There is. You can use Particle system's hair to do it. With a sphere as a dupli. It's emitted from **vertices**, Random unchecked. These are Advanced options. Adjust the dupli's size. When done, convert the particles to mesh. Your nucleus should look like this

[image]

Then you can color "protons and neutrons" - select a small sphere; <kbd>Shift+G</kbd> > Type;  deselect the big sphere; apply material color; checker deselect and add second material color. The result is a two color nucleus.

And if you want a cube you need to subdivide it first. And use vertex groups (make **some** effort and read about it) for locating different atoms.

Comment: When you say "color protons and neutrons" how shall I do it?

Comment: Checker deselect to add second color.

Comment: I tried to follow what you wrote, however, I could not really. I also do not understand what will be the result? Can you please provide more instructions?