# How can I connect a set of vertices to make a 3D model, with a script?

Tags: scripting, objects

I have a set of vertices in an spreadsheet from which I want to make an object. I only need it to connect the vertices and then fill in the faces. How can I do this in Blender?

Comment: very related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/how-to-create-a-mesh-programmatically-without-bmesh/2416#2416

Comment: Is the desired result a line or a mesh?

Comment: A simple python script should do the trick. I'm not qualified to provide a good answer of how though. But it is possible.

Comment: you should have more info ( rather than the verts list ), there are many possibilities in 3d , you can try Convex Hull function in blender ( search in space-bar menu )

Comment: You could write a VBA program to create an .obj file and import it into Blender. Then you could select verticies individually and fill the faces you needed. I was thinking about this today. Perhaps a python program that would somehow join all certified in the same plane while checking for duplicates?
Thanks for the idea of exporting .objs from Excel!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27592/3710

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest path here is to export from excel as a `.csv` (comma separated values) in a column-format that the existing .csv readers/importers  written for Blender understand. Here's an [example of one such addon](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?211735-A-Script-to-Import-a-CSV-File-and-Create-Meshes-(for-Blender-2-5x-or-later)&p=2866999&viewfull=1#post2866999) . This means you don't have to write any import code.

But if you did want some autonomy over the import code, you might write something like this (but use a .csv format it is much easier to parse):

your csv, let's call it `circle.csv`

```
x,y,z
0.000000,1.000000,0
0.500000,0.866025,0
0.866025,0.500000,0
1.000000,0.000000,0
0.866025,-0.500000,0
0.500000,-0.866025,0
0.000000,-1.000000,0
-0.500000,-0.866025,0
-0.866025,-0.500000,0
-1.000000,-0.000000,0
-0.866025,0.500000,0
-0.500000,0.866025,0
```

The least amount of code needed to read a file like that into blender might look something like this. You run from Text Editor, (but remember to get the path to the file correct first..)

```
import csv
import os
import bpy

filename = 'circle.csv'
directory = '/home/zeffii/Desktop'  # <-- if you have linux or osx
# directory = r'c:\some\directory'  # <-- if windows, the r is important
# directory = 'c:/some/directory'  # <-- if windows (alternative)

fullpath = os.path.join(directory, filename)

with open(fullpath, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    ofile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(ofile) # <-- skip the x,y,z header

    # this makes a generator of the remaining non-empty lines
    rows = (r for r in ofile if r)

    # this converts the string representation of each line
    # to an x,y,z list, and stores it in the verts list.
    verts = [[float(i) for i in r] for r in rows]

if verts:
    # join vertices into one uninterrupted chain of edges.
    edges = [[i, i+1] for i in range(len(verts)-1)]

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("mesh_name")
    mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces=[])
    mesh.update()

    obj = bpy.data.objects.new("obj_name", mesh)

    scene = bpy.context.scene
    scene.objects.link(obj)
```

Comment: The one adjustment I would make is edges = [ [i,i+1] for i in range( len(verts)-1) ] which would create edges stringing all the vertices together.