# Draw a curve through coordinates

Tags: bezier-curves, coordinates

I have an excel files of coordinates. There's a lot of coordinates so slowly plot them one by one is not practical? Is there anyway to create a curve though them automatically?

Thanks lots and really appreciate your help!!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34018/python-script-that-reads-text-file-containing-coordinates-and-creates-a-path-cur

Comment: If the suggested duplicate doesn't prove to be helpful, please update your question and say something like 'I tried the suggested Answer, but it doesn't work for me because (insert reason)'