# Code for creating a mesh from a collection of points in Blender

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, objects, coordinates

I have a set of points in a text [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ApyKbzkgjKk11x-RDW8kHsPEp7m_ZOMb/view?usp=sharing) that define the edges of a solid object. Each line in the file is a collection of points (x,y,z) which form a closed loop. Stacking these loops forms the object.

I am trying to create a surface mesh of the object and write it to an.STL file. What would be the best way to do it in Blender? Can the process be automated with a script?

I am totally new to blender and have no idea where to start. Any pointers are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:
I understand that once all the points are loaded into Blender, I can connect the vertices in each layer to form edges. But, how are the vertices defined?

Here is what I have:

```
with open('contoursb1_0.25res_60SCD.txt','r') as file:
test = [[[float(i) for i in pt.split(',')] for pt in line.split()] for line in file]
```

Now for each layer, I would like to go across the list and create vertices and edges. How should I proceed? I found this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31121/how-can-i-connect-a-set-of-vertices-to-make-a-3d-model-with-a-script) helpful, but am unable to create vertices. I am also a novice in python. So if you have any suggestions or see any errors and point them out, I would be greatful.