# Mesh from CSV data

Tags: modeling, python, mesh, csv

I trying to create a mesh from GPS lat&long coordinates combined with WiFi RSSI data. When imported the data looks like this

[image: Lat&long + RSSI]

I've been playing around with different ways to create a solid mesh, but none seem to work very well.

I was hoping to achieve something like a heatmap geography of a route where strong WiFi signals show as spikes.

Along the lines of what I wanted to achieve:
[image]

Comment: There is an abundance of similar questions here in the blender stackexchange 
 (visualization of data). Please use the search. Here is even a question using the same image as you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76535/create-model-from-xyz-data-points?rq=1. If nothing matches please explain your data in more detail

Comment: This is going to depend on input data are lat and long  in a simple grid pattern,?

Comment: I've tried working from that post and it just seems to output a line with no faces.
@batFINGER What do you mean with a simple grid pattern?

Comment: In your example pic the x, y of mesh is a grid.  The "heat" z isn't.  If the data is ordered in lat long grid then making a mesh like above is pretty simple. If the lats and longs are a  willy nilly hodge podge, maybe not so simple,

Comment: The lat long should be prober, but yeah the heat (rssi) is all over the place. Any pointers on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated.