# making 3d surface using list of vertices coordinates

Tags: python, animation, mesh, vertices, faces

i want to animate a changing 3d surface (i.e. an ocean wave). the surface cannot be defined with a single z function and instead I have been defining as a list of coordinates that lie on the surface. when I use matplotlib the software is able to make a smooth surface based on coordinates easily, but on blender I cant figure out how to add faces.

I use a bmesh to plot the coordinates which I give in the form [(x, y, z), ...]. However, I can't figure out how best to add edges and faces to make a complete surface. I would like to make the faces square so each square's corners are marker by the four closest vertices.

[image: a simple example of a surface plotted with the method being used so far]

here is a surface made up of individually plotted vertices on a mesh. If I use the 'make edge/face' option it adds one big face bounded by every single vertex as far as I can tell.

[image: after using make surface]

is there a way to achieve what I want without having to manually add faces to each group of four vertices? preferably in a way that might be efficient enough to animate quickly.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76535/create-model-from-xyz-data-points

Comment: @batFINGER that is perfect, thank you!