# How to create mesh surface using csv datapoints?

Tags: mesh, csv

I have a csv data which contains x, y, z columns.

I want to visualize this data as a surface mesh. From the csv file, I can load the data via csv mesh Importer add-on in Blender 2.5 and Statistical data in Blender 2.8. But in both cases, the data is loading as a scatter plot. So because of this, I am unable to load as an object so as to convert vertices to surface.

I could load the file in VTK paraview too but with same points rather than creating a mesh.

So, my question is "How to create mesh surface from csv data points in Blender" ?

I have attached the obtained results in Blender and Paraview.

Please let me know if there are any approaches present.

Thanks and Regards,
Sunag R A.

[image: Image in Paraview]

[image: Blender 2.8 Statistical data view]

[image: Blender 2.5 mesh importer view]

Comment: Try https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76535/create-model-from-xyz-data-points/76612#76612 can work or not depending on the data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try MeshLab is free. Here is a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38mt3kpsxd4