# How do I import a CSV file of XYZ Cartesian coordinates with descriptions and point numbers into Blender?

Tags: csv

I have a CSV file in the format "point number, X, Y, Z, point description" in meters. These are WGS84 Earth Centered Earth fixed coordinates where the mass center of the earth is the origin at 0,0,0 meters.

Is it possible to import this file into Blender and have the point number and the description displayed?
Here is a sample -
721,-48487.100,-18132553.751,10409418.923,MP 0.26 (EL 19.0)
722,-48259.708,-18131855.882,10410627.254,MP 0.53 (EL 18.9)
723,-48033.270,-18131157.061,10411837.321,MP 0.79 (EL 18.9)
724,-47805.212,-18130458.373,10413046.668,MP 1.06 (EL 19.0)
725,-47582.647,-18129758.901,10414257.385,MP 1.33 (EL 18.9)
726,-47367.558,-18129058.792,10415468.554,MP 1.60 (EL 18.9)

I am new to Blender and I do not program. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: how would you want the "point number and the description" displayed? I can imaging a large point cloud roughly the shape of a sphere but if each point had a text object with constraints to face the camera it would be very messy. Can you upload a sketch/mock up of what you need?

Comment: relevant but needs Python understanding https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27536/csv-import-pointcloud-into-blender which I am not sure you can get away from.