# How can I create a 3D model of the CIELAB color space?

Tags: 3d-printing, coordinates, csv

My professor and I are trying to create and print a 3D model of the [CIELAB color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space) for one of my Master's studies.

He has provided me with a CSV of the color space's data points (which you can imagine is a lot) and I am hoping there is a way I can import that file, or convert the file if needed so that the software can create the model from the data. (I don't even know for sure if it can do that.) I am looking for just the creation of the model, not the coloring of it right now.

I don't have a lot of experience with Blender except for the donut tutorial by BlenderGuru on YouTube. I really hope someone can help me or knows of a pre-existing model that I can use.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76535  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71458 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27536