# How to create faces/edges from vertices/points?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, point-clouds

I can easily delete the faces and edges using ***delete only edges & faces*** option. It would be nice to have the possibility to reverse this operation. 
[image]

Is there a way to create an universal script that may automatically create the faces/edges from vertices/points? This is easy when the vertices are conected with edges- you can use a ***Fill Holes*** option, but for vertices/points only it doesn't work. Similar question was asked before  ([Create model from XYZ data points](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76535/create-model-from-xyz-data-points)) but it is focused on a defined case. Is there a way to create the script that will join vertices/points for ***any*** object (like in photogrammetry)?

Comment: Is there any cues that the script can use the regenerate the faces? I mean,  if the set of vertices is the only information, there are too many possible answers.

Comment: I think @Allosteric brought in a good topic. Are you considering things like vertices index, normals,... everithing lost or inconsistent but the location? If this is the case, it's a point cloud meshing problem (https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?241950-A-Script-to-Skin-a-Point-Cloud-(for-Blender-2-6x-or-Later)) (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7028/wrapping-a-mesh-around-point-cloud-with-cavities)

Comment: @Carlo Thanks for the links! *Point Cloud Skinner* seems to be a thing I need. I asked this question because I want to make meshes from particles. I want to emit particles from object, convert it to vertices and then to meshes. I want to test a retopology posibilities of this method plus it may be helpful for morphing objects (imagine you can generate the same amount of evenly distributed particles for two objects with different vertex count and then convert them to meshes- it'll alow you to morph objects easily using shape keys).