# How to make a mesh from vertices/points via triangulation?

Tags: mesh, point-clouds

I have a set of points which each of them can be represented as bezier curve. What I need to do is to make a mesh from them. Probably this meshing algorithm must be based on triangulation. However my points are like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to make a mesh from a these points?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7028/wrapping-a-mesh-around-point-cloud-with-cavities.

Comment: @MrZak No. It's not.

Comment: What you state lacks any details whatsover. If you are so sure then edit the question, state how existing addon doesn't help you, show any researching effort in regard to the context of your question

Comment: Because it's convex hull. I don't want concex hull they must be like delaunay triangulation. And his points can be just point cloud but mine must be draw as line, bezier curve and my triangulation must be with those lines.